# Are there any good resources on developing ASP.NET for Windows CE Internet Explorer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, windows-ce

I've been tasked with creating a web app to be consumed by a mobile device sporting Windows CE 5.0 (and some with Windows CE 4.2).

I've found a host of things that seem to work fine in IE6 on my desktop, but fail when rendered in IE for Windows CE.

IE6 is bad enough as it is...does it lose any more functionality on an embedded system?

Are there quirks that a developer would need to know about?

AJAX seems extremely unlikely. JavaScript seems quirky when linking to a .js file. Panels with scrollbars are finicky. Textboxes can't get focus. DefaultButtons on a form don't work.

Any help or resources you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have already found this one, but anyway:

http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/02/26/the-pocket-or-mobile-internet-explorer/

Some of his links are messed up, if you see a broken link just replace "httpp" with "http".

Comment: I have not seen that. Very helpful! Thanks.